# Linux X window system C KeyPress xkey.keycode to char?

Tags: linux, c, gcc, ascii, x11

KeyPress -> xkey.keycode возвращает unsigned int. подумал что может код какого то символа. Но возвращаемое значение не совпадает ни с ASCII ни с Unicode. Как из этого получить символ нажатой клавиши и вывести в консоль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xkey.keycode`, как [описано](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/keyboard-encoding.html) в «Xlib manual», — это *код клавиши* (*KeyCode*), который представляет собой некое произвольное значение полученное от аппаратно/платформо-зависимого «драйвера» и в большинстве случаев не представляет прямого интереса для прикладного программиста. Для прикладного использования необходимо получить соответствующий *Символ клавиши* (*KeySym*), который по задумке подразумевает собой логическое значение, то что с точки зрения X-сервера непосредственно «написано на клавише», которую нажал пользователь. На практике KeySym-значения латиницы соответствуют ASCII, но AFAIK это не гарантируется.

Каждому коду клавиши обычно соответствует несколько символов, выбор между которыми производится на основе модификаторов (<kbd>*Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) и настроек (раскладки клавиатуры).

Дабы получить *KeySym* из события ввода интерес представляют прежде всего две функции:

- [`XLookupKeysym()`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/keyboard/XLookupKeysym.html) позволяет получить произвольный символ соответствующий клавише, прежде всего интерес представляет «основной» символ с индексом `0`, полезна для реализации горячих клавиш.
- [`XLookupString()`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XLookupString.html) позволяет получить вариант символа с учётом модификаторов и раскладки, а также строку символов в текущей (возможно многобайтовой) локали, которая эта клавиша должна выводить<sup>*</sup>.

Пример использования (простой клавиатурный аналог [`xev`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=xev&category=1&russian=2) «для бедных»):

```
// Build: gcc -lX11 xev-simple.c
#include <assert.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>

int main() {
    Display *dpy;
    int screen;
    Window win;
    Window rootWin;
    XEvent event;

    setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    if (dpy == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    screen = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    rootWin = RootWindow(dpy, screen);
    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, rootWin, 10, 10, 100, 100, 1,
            BlackPixel(dpy, screen), WhitePixel(dpy, screen));
    XSelectInput(dpy, win, KeyPressMask);
    XMapWindow(dpy, win);

    while(1) {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &event);
        switch(event.type) {
        case KeyPress:
            {
                char buff[8];
                KeySym symLS;
                KeySym sym=XLookupKeysym(&event.xkey, 0);

                XLookupString(&event.xkey, buff, sizeof(buff), &symLS, 0);

                fprintf(stderr, "keycode: %02x, keysym: %04lx (%8s) "
                        "XLookupString: keycode:%04lx (%14s), \"%s\"\n",
                        event.xkey.keycode, sym, XKeysymToString(sym),
                        symLS, XKeysymToString(symLS), buff);

                if (sym == XK_q) {
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            break;
        case MappingNotify:
            XRefreshKeyboardMapping(&event.xmapping);
            break;
        }
    }

    assert (!"Nobody escapes from the infinite look");
}
```

---

Пример вывода:
$ gcc -lX11 xev-simple.c && ./a.out

```
keycode: 34, keysym: 007a (       z) XLookupString: keycode:007a (             z), "z"
keycode: 32, keysym: ffe1 ( Shift_L) XLookupString: keycode:ffe1 (       Shift_L), ""
keycode: 3c, keysym: 002e (  period) XLookupString: keycode:003e (       greater), ">"
keycode: 6c, keysym: fe03 (ISO_Level3_Shift) XLookupString: keycode:fe03 (ISO_Level3_Shift), ""
keycode: 3c, keysym: 002e (  period) XLookupString: keycode:00bb (guillemotright), "»"
keycode: 3b, keysym: 002c (   comma) XLookupString: keycode:00ab ( guillemotleft), "«"
keycode: 32, keysym: ffe1 ( Shift_L) XLookupString: keycode:ffe1 (       Shift_L), ""
keycode: 42, keysym: fe08 (ISO_Next_Group) XLookupString: keycode:ffe5 (     Caps_Lock), ""
keycode: 34, keysym: 007a (       z) XLookupString: keycode:005a (             Z), "Z"
keycode: 35, keysym: 0078 (       x) XLookupString: keycode:0058 (             X), "X"
keycode: 3e, keysym: ffe2 ( Shift_R) XLookupString: keycode:ffe2 (       Shift_R), ""
keycode: 35, keysym: 0078 (       x) XLookupString: keycode:0078 (             x), "x"
keycode: 32, keysym: ffe1 ( Shift_L) XLookupString: keycode:ffe1 (       Shift_L), ""
keycode: 42, keysym: fe08 (ISO_Next_Group) XLookupString: keycode:ffe5 (     Caps_Lock), ""
keycode: 34, keysym: 007a (       z) XLookupString: keycode:06d1 (   Cyrillic_ya), "я"
keycode: 35, keysym: 0078 (       x) XLookupString: keycode:06de (  Cyrillic_che), "ч"
keycode: 3e, keysym: ffe2 ( Shift_R) XLookupString: keycode:ffe2 (       Shift_R), ""
keycode: 23, keysym: 005d (bracketright) XLookupString: keycode:06ff (Cyrillic_HARDSIGN), "Ъ"
keycode: 18, keysym: 0071 (       q) XLookupString: keycode:06ca (Cyrillic_shorti), "й"
```

---

<sup>*На практике для полноценно-локализируемых приложений вместо этого желательно использовать [`XmbLookupString()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xmblookupstring) и её друзей, которые полагаются на XIM, но это уже более сложная тема, заслуживающая отдельного вопроса.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать Dictionaryи там сопоставить интовому аски коду клавиши русский символ
и при получении кода клавиши сможете обращаться к Dictionary

Comment: Плохой совет из серии «забей шуруп молотком»... это даст непереносимый код, который прибит к конкретной реализации клавиатуры на конкретной платформе...

Answer (score 0):

Ну этот метод и не должен вам возвращать код символа. Он возвращает грубо говоря код клавиши. Допустим (пользовал французскую раскладку как-то) клавиатура AZERTY и QWERTY - вы нажимаете Z или W (в зависимости от раскладки), но получите один и тот же код.

Вы лучше скажите - зачем вам через X11 получать символ??? И точно ли оно вам нужно...

Comment: задание в универе такое дали - нужно отображать окно в линуксе(!) и выводить информацию о нажатии кнопок, клавишь, и ресайзе окошка в консоль и в само окошко тоже.